# Retrieve marker coordinates in ARToolKit

Tags: c++, coordinates, artoolkit

How can I retrieve the coordinates of a marker in ARToolKit and save like a 2D coordinates.
So I can try to cut a jpg file using those coordinates.

Comment: So, you're asking for the 2D image coordinates, or the 3D "world" coordinates?

Comment: more or less i kon the marker in the artoolkit have 3d coordinates because its use the deep closer to the video cam larger box far away smaller box, But i know need the to see if its closer or far away just the position on screen. i dont know if you can understand me english not my native language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2D positions of both the corners and center of a marker are easily retrievable. They are stored in the ARMarkerInfo structure. The corners are ARMarkerInfo.vertex[][] and the center is ARMarkerInfo.pos[].

The easiest place to retrieve this is in the main detection loop, e.g. mainLoop in the simple or simpleLite examples.

Comment: thanks bleater, i will see this and later tell you something ;)

Comment: thanks @bleater but how can i use the ARMarkerInfo.vertex[][] coordinates so i can draw a polygon using the same position i get from there?

Comment: Have a look in ARToolKit at util/mk_patt source, since mk_patt does exactly that, drawing a polygon around detected trapezoidal regions.